Determining the Sign of $E$ When Solving the Time-Independent Schrödinger Equation
I am having trouble understanding how to choose the sign of  $E$  when solving the time-independent Schrödinger equation. I understand that for potentials where $V(\pm\infty) < E$, we want scattering solutions, and for $V(\pm\infty) > E$, we want bound state solutions. However, there are cases where this criterion does not apply
A good example for my question is the step potential question from Griffiths (Problem 2.34).
Consider a step potential:
$$
V(x) = \begin{cases}
V_0 & \text{if } x > 0, \\
0 & \text{if } x \leq 0.
\end{cases}
$$
Given that $E<V_0$ I want to find the solutions to the Schrödinger equation for each region and then apply the boundary conditions.
I am having trouble deciding how to solve the Schrödinger equation for the left region where $V=0$
The time-independent Schrödinger equation for this region is:
$$
\frac{d^2 \Psi}{dx^2} = -\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2} \Psi
$$
My confusion about the choosing the sing of E:
If I assume E > 0, I find scattering state solutions. $k^2=\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}$ then the solution is $\Psi=Ae^{ikx}+Be^{-ikx}$
If I assume E < 0, I find bound state solutions. $k^2=\frac{-2mE}{\hbar^2}$ then the solution is $\Psi=Ae^{kx}$
These two lead to different types of wavefunctions. How do I make the correct choice for E in this situation or in general?

The energy can never be less than the minimum of the potential energy. So, in this case, it has to be $E>0$. I remember that this is on Griffiths book, in chapter 2 i suppose.

You are correct that to have normalizable solutions, you need  $E > V_{min}$ . In this case,  $V_{min} = 0$ .
However, for a Dirac delta potential, we can look for both scattering and bound-state solutions. For that, we assume  E > 0  for scattering solutions and  E < 0  for bound-state solutions, depending on what we want as a solution.

Normally, if the potential is finite at infinity, one often set this potential to be $0$: $V(\infty)=0$.  In this case, bound states have $E<0$.  Thus, for hydrogen, all $E<0$ for bound states.  This is the same choice as one would do in classical mechanics.   Likewise in a finite well (finite depth), one chooses the potential to be $0$ outside the well and all bound states have $E<0$.
On the other hand, for the harmonic oscillator and the infinite well, the potential is unbounded so the bound state have $E>0$.
In principle you can always "shift up" or "shift down" the reference energy by some finite amount.  For instance, in the Morse potential, one may choose the dissociation energy to be $0$ and then all bound states have $E<0$.  On the other hand, one can also choose the bottom of the potential to be $0$, in which case all $E>0$ but the bound states appear when $E< E_{\text{dissociation}}$.
Note that (as alluded to in a comment), the bound state energies are always greater than the minimum energy of the potential.
